# MongoDB PHP connection management class

Tags: php, oop, mongodb

I'm looking for a decent example of creating a PHP class that will handle connections to multiple MongoDB databases. I'm working on a project that will have at least five separate databases. It would be extremely process heavy if I were to connect/disconnect each time I make a call to the database.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: google can, it pointed me towards [this man page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php), pretty sure that there are some classes out there - I've only checked _the first hit on google_

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Doctrine2 with it's MongoDB](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/) Features

When this project is large and will be maintained for some time, you should also consider taking a framework like [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) into account, which [harmonies perfectly with Doctrine2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html). Though it might feels like a huge rock to climb at the beginning, it is worth the reading and once you're into it, you are not going to make a website manually by hand anymore :)

Comment: I would suggest starting with the [doctrine/mongodb](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb) library rather than ODM. It adds some functionality over the PECL driver without the overhead of a persistence layer, which might not be necessary. It currently does not have its own documentation, but many parts of the ODM's documentation apply to a degree. Thankfully, the code should be simple enough to grok via inline documentation.